# How to read a file on Hololens with C++

Tags: c++, uwp, native, hololens

I am trying to read a file in a test/debug UWP application that is being deployed to Hololens. I can put the file on the device with the device portal, but am unable to find the correct path to open the file.

I am using the MSFT BasicXrApp_uwp example as a basis, and have included FileUtility which has a `FindFileInAppFolder` function. This is consistently failing to find the file, with the error:
`"The file should be embeded in app folder in debug build."`,
after letting me know the app folder is:

`C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\364f83f4-6e13-42e4-8253-71dd3040951cVS.Debug_ARM.mikeh\`

The part `364f83f4-6e13-42e4-8253-71dd3040951cVS` is recognisable in the device portal as the User Folders/LocalAppData folder, but the Debug_ARM.mikeh part is not visible on the portal.

I am using C++ and trying to do the file reading in a static, non uwp library if possible (pointing that out so I don't get suggestions to use UWP async stuff, if that is possible).

So, how do I embed my file in the app folder, or how do I place the file so I can read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the folder path which FindFileInAppFolder method returns is the [InstalledLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation?view=winrt-19041#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation) of the current package, but what you checked in the device portal is [LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder?view=winrt-19041)/[LocalCacheFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localcachefolder?view=winrt-19041), for more information about what different between them please see: [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

> how do I embed my file in the app folder, or how do I place the file so I can read it?

You can place your file in the LocalState folder by Device Portal and get this folder path through ApplicationData.LocalFolder Property, the path should be like: `C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\364f83f4-6e13-42e4-8253-71dd3040951c\LocalState`. For how to access the files via C++ you can use for example [File access sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FileAccess)

Comment: Thanks, that does help, as I can find the file now using winrt + UWP. 

However, I'm passing the filename to a library that is STL based, and reads a file using a `std::istream`. I am unable to open the file using `std::ifstream ifs(filename);`

Should I expect to be able to? 
From what I've read I should be able to use existing static libs with a UWP application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an answer here as there's more room than a comment.
I found a few extra things useful. I added in the cppWinRT nuget package to my application.
I did need to use the "async stuff", for example:

```
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;

StorageFolder storageFolder= KnownFolders::GetFolderForUserAsync(nullptr, KnownFolderId::PicturesLibrary).get();
```

This let me find a file I'd uploaded ot the Pictures Library. But I couldn't open it after passing the path to my existing library:

```
const auto sampleFile = storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName).get();
std::wstring path = sampleFile.Path();

MyLibraryCall(to_string(path));
```

`MyLibraryCall` would try and open an ifstream, and even using `std::ifstream::in`  would fail.
So I copied the file to the temp directory, where I could open it and process it.
This is pretty hacky but it did what I needed, which is let me load an .obj file that was rejected by the 3D parts viewer.

The loop over all filenames is because `storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName).get()` throws an exception if it fails, which for me I could not catch properly.

```
StorageFolder tempFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current().TemporaryFolder();
std::wstring path;
auto  files = tempFolder.GetFilesAsync().get();
for (auto file : files) 
{
  if (file.Name() == fileName) {
  path = file.Path();
  break;
  }
}
if (!path.size()) {
  // hasn't been copied into temp
  StorageFile movedFile = sampleFile.CopyAsync(tempFolder).get(); 
  path = movedFile.Path();
}
MyLibraryCall(to_string(path));
```

Anyway- not the greatest but that will hopefully help someone else looking for a quick and dirty way to process a file on a hololens/UWP app.